# How much less secure is an algorithm that gives feedback that the password is one character off?

Tags: authentication, password-hashing

If we had a stupid login procedure (SLP for short) like in [this comic](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2018/01/18/what-if-its-only-one-character-off/); it gives feedback on login, if the submitted password is one character off.

Would a longer password be less secure? What would the break-even point?

If I had a password with length 1, I would always get feedback, that I am one off, so the SLP would not make the password less secure. If I have length 2, I would get feedback half the time, so the SLP would make a password with length 2 as secure as a password with length 1?

The algorithm I would use to hash those password would be:

```
hash(password)
for(i=0; i++; i < len(password)
  hash(password.deleteChar(i))
```

For login:

```
if(hashAndMatch(password)){
  login()
} else {
  for(i=0; i++; i < len(password){
    if(hashAndMatch(password.deleteChar(i))){
      giveFeedBack()
      break;
    }
   }
   error('Wrong password or username')
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that there are $95$ possible characters for a password. Thus, there are $95^n$ possible $n$ character passwords. You would like for brute force to take on the order of that many guesses to get right, $O(95^n)$.

In your case, given the additional information, once you know you have all characters right except one, it takes only an additional $95$ calls to get the exact password. So, attacking this would take $95^{n-1}+95=O(95^{n-1})$ work.

So, basically it decreases the security by one character.

Comment: If you know that you are one character off (but don't know which one), you only need $94n$ more tries (for every character try the 94 alternatives). I'm not sure where $95^{n-1}$ came from. The proposed password hint degrades security to essentially nothing.

Comment: Note the code in the question only allowed for an extra letter. So we actually neee to guess passwords of length n+1. A different deffenition for off by one is possible but I don't see which this answer would match.

Comment: @mikero, I'm assuming you start from no information at all, not that you start with the case of knowing a password that is off by one.

Comment: @meir, yeah, the code and the description don't match, so I went with the description.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided only handles 1 extra charachter mistake. It checks password length variants for each password and therefor it weakens security by a factor of password length.
Let password length be $n$ and the size of the charachter set be $k$ so normally the password space would be $k^n$ and with the proposed space it is effectively reduced to $k^n/(n+1)$

If you instead allow replacing one chatachter in the password you have $n*(k-1)$ variants for each password and strength would be reduced by the same amount.

We should separate between two forms of attack, an online attack where each password guess is sent to the validation code which will attempt several variants and offline against the hash. An online attack  will typically only allow a very slow guess rate with proper implementation and variants of very common passwords are not likely to be common themselves. For the online attack this argueably doesn't hurt security measureably.

An offline attack against a leaked password hash will allow the full speedup but only indirectly. When attacking the hash we don't get direct benefit of the variant checking. But when we select the number of iterations for the key derivation function we limit ourselves by the computing budget for validating a password. So with variant checking we need to lower the number of hash iterations to meet the same compute budget.

Alternatively to variant checking, I recall some research which looked favourably into making the hash ignore certain aspects of the password for instance, case of the first letter. They showed a significant percentage of failed password attempts (which later succeed) can be avoided with minimal impact on security.